# How to SUM Datetime per column

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, mysql-workbench

i want to sum columns

> logstep_1 + logstep_2 + logstep_3 till logstep_9

type data of the column is datetime but i want the result as time.

thank you.

[here is my structure table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zgmp.png)

*sorry for my bad english

Comment: did you try `SUM()` ?

Comment: yes, but sum function is sum per row, i want sum per column sir ..  want get result of  logstep_1 + logstep_2 + logstep_3

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: Agree with @Strawberry but maybe something like `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(logstep_1)) + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(logstep_2))` etc. Not really much information to go on. Maybe indicate the purpose ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS some of your `logstep_*` columns value is `NULL` so try like this with `ifnull`, I've added only three columns you can try with all of your columns. Hope this will help you.

```
select SEC_TO_TIME(
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ifnull(logstep_1, 0)) + 
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ifnull(logstep_2, 0)) + 
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ifnull(logstep_3, 0))
) as logstep_sum_in_time
from log_step
```

Comment: it's show me seconds then how i convert it to time format sir ?
 https://s15.postimg.cc/dsxp68zkr/Screenshot_2018-07-26_23-25-04.png

Comment: @RobyFirnandoYusuf I've updated my answer, check it out again and let me know whether it is working or not?